# Grub doesn't detect Windows 10 Pro (Legacy boot)

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I recently installed Arch Linux. I want to dual boot Windows 10 and Arch Linux. Windows 10 is not appearing in grub menu.

I've tried

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

but that didn't help. I HAVE googled but I couldn't find anything that could help me, most forums are based on UEFI systems. My system doesn't support UEFI.

I have an HP Z400.
Latest Bios version available for it.
Arch Linux is installed on a 500GB Seagate Hard drive and Windows is installed on a 500GB WD Hard drive.

How can I make windows 10 appear on my grub?

Comment: Do you have Windows fast start up off? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148120/ubuntu-18-0x-not-detecting-windows-ssd-during-installation & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on#963100
 Note that Windows updates turn it back on, so whenever issue, check if it is back on.

Comment: @oldfred it was on before, but I turned it off and tried `grub-mkconfig` again, alas no luck. Windows is still not showing up.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair